# Get next a tag in nested ul tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested unordered list representing a tree hierarchy. There can be many deeply nested ul tags in the unordered list. Very simple example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="disallowed">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="disallowed">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, some links can have class "allowed". When a link like that is clicked, I would like to get a next a tag in the tree and if it has class "disallowed", change it to "allowed".

How can I get the next a tag in the tree?

UPDATE:

What I mean. Before:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a><!-- this gets clicked on -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="disallowed">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="disallowed">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

HTML changes to this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="allowed">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="disallowed">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And so on.

Comment: as I can see it, there's no `li` with class...

Comment: @Reigel I corrected the typo. I meant a tag, of course.

Comment: I still don't get it :D Can you put `before-after` codes of html. before a clicked happen(you have it already), and after a clicked happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.allowed').live(function() {
    var links= $('a');
    var ix= links.index(this);
    if (ix!==-1 && ix<links.length-1)
        links.eq(ix+1).removeClass('disallowed').addClass('allowed');
});
```

- this uses `live()` to catch clicks, assuming that after after a link is changed to `class="allowed"`, clicking that should perform the same action
- it looks for the next link on the whole page. If you only want to check inside a particular container, use that as the parent to find links in, eg. `var links= $('#myul a');`, for efficiency and to prevent it affecting other page links

Comment: Thanks, I will go try it, If it works, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var el = null;
      $('ul li a.allowed').click(function(){
        el = $(this);
        while($(el).closest('.ul')){
          el = $(el).closest('.ul');
          var a = $(el).find('li a.disallowed:first');
          if(a){
            $(a).removeclass('disallowed').addClass('allowed');
            return true;
          }
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is('.allowed')) {
            var nextElem = $(this).next('ul').length?$(this).next('ul'):$(this).closest('li').next('li');
            nextElem.find('a:first').
                filter(function(){
                    return $(this).is('.disallowed');
                }).
                removeClass('disallowed').
                addClass('allowed');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

## Phew! [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qJNZ5/)

Comment: Yes but click links after 11th is allowed. Then click the 11th link and see what happens (more than one link after the 11th become allowed).

Comment: okay, I don't get you. 11th and 12th not allowed right? I click 10th, 11th become allowed. I click 11th, 12th become allowed. But if I click 11th without clicking 10th first, 12th will not be allowed. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: If 11th is allowed and I click it, next three links become allowed.

Comment: I am writing in literary English and all my sentences are completely clear and comprehensible. I don't understand what you have problem with. Others got what I meant :P

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
$('a.allowed').click(function(){
    $(this).next().find('a:first').attr('class', 'allowed');
});
```

this will make all the a tags under the ul next to the a link that was clicked have a class `allowed`.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't have to be case. The above HTML structure is just an example, There could be another nested ul inside.

Comment: so you want all `a` under the link that is clicked should turn to `allowed`? in your edit, the only link that is changed is just the first `a` that is found.